# Automatic type casting in google bigquery

Tags: casting, google-bigquery

I have a query in standard SQL of bigquery:

```
insert into table1 (valriable1) select x as variable1 from table2;
```

where variable1 is a float and x is an integer in table2 (I want to put an integer into a float), but I receive an error saying:

> invalid schema update. Field x has changed type

the same problem when putting an integer into a string. I don't want to use cast function. Is there any other way for automatic type casting (like what we have in sql server)

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to use cast functions ?

Comment: I have hundreds of queries in sql server that I want to run them on my GBQ dataset. All of them have auto-casting but GBQ does not allow me for this.

Comment: What kind of statement are you using

INSERT

or

SELECT with append to table?

With INSERT you should see errors along the lines of 

Query column 1 has type FLOAT64 which cannot be inserted
into column column_int, which has type INT64

While you reported some other error.